# MainActivity fails on phone

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm doing a very simple example where I want a button to generate a notification. I'm not looking for interactivity (so no Intent); just that a simple notification should be published.
The UI contains just a single button, which is clicked to generate the notification.

Here's the code:

```
package ank.notificationdemo;

import android.R.drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn_notify;
    Notification noti;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_notify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_notify);
        noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
               .setContentTitle("Alert!").setContentText("Shipwreck at 22N-56E. Hurry!").setSmallIcon(drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
               .build();

        btn_notify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                mgr.notify(100, noti);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that this works on the Emulator, but the main activity fails to load on my Android phone (running ICS). Other examples have, however, worked fine.

Any clue as to what might be going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide logcat report?

Comment: For gathering logcat report use 'adb logcat'

Comment: @Dimmerg Do you mean logcat report from the Eclipse IDE? It looks considerable in size to me. Should I just paste everything here or upload the text file somewhere and provide the link? (Sorry if the question is dumb!)

Comment: do you see a stack trace in log cat ?

Comment: @ankush you can paste it for example on pastebin.com and provide link here. Note on strings with red color - it's stack trace and error description.

Comment: Here's the full-fledged Logact output of a sample run on Emulator: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sw0tyyeL)

Comment: Sorry if the output is too long. I can select only the red lines if that is more convenient (I wish there were a better way to do that than manually, though!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok

Tried your code out and turns out the issue is with using `Notification.Builder.build()`

Looks like they only changed it to `.build()` in Jelly Bean and in the Latest update to the Support Library.

So just import the new Support Library and use the `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead. Should solve your problem.

Comment: But that means my app breaks on versions less than 4.0, isn't it?

Comment: not if you use the support library. if you use that then the method .build() will work fine.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Thank you, thank you, thank you!! I've been applying my head to this for the past two days, and finally I have a method that works!
But what did you mean by "Looks like they only changed it to .build() in Jelly Bean and in the Latest update to the Support Library" ?
Does that mean the whole Class structure got replaced by a single .build()? If not, wasn't it .build() before also? Please do explain and thank you very much!

Comment: The method used to be `.getNotification()`. So anything pre-JB (4.1-) would have to use that. They changed it in JB, i assume, to be more correct in terms of best practice, i.e. having a Builder that doesn't build makes very little sense. Then in order to accomodate existing apps, they put the same change in the Support Library, so now you can just reference `NotificationCompat` and can use `.build()`. Hope this explains it...ahem lol.

Comment: Lol. Still kinda fuzzy but you've done a great job! Many thanks from my side!

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similiar problem with my Nexus4. It however was resolved by setting an Intent in the NotificationBuilder.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding an intent still crashes. How can I paste the revised code here?